# how to use COALESCE in oracle to combine data from two rows

Tags: oracle

I have the following query which is inside a loop and is breaking

```
SELECT   COALESCE(v_user_grade || ', ', '') || user_grade
          INTO v_user_grade
          FROM EXPIRATION_HISTORY__2
           WHERE hist_id = v_test;
```

So basically in each iteration of the loop we get a new value for v_test.  In some cases this query would return multiple rows. that is when it is breaking.

What I want is:

Data in EXPIRATION_HISTORY__2:

```
hist_id    user_grade
301     ADMIN
302     ADMIN
302     USER
```

so now based on the above data. ...in the end of the iteration where `v_test = 302`. I would want `v_user_grade` to contain (`ADMIN, USER`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following link describes exactly that what you want:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php

> **String Aggregation Techniques**
>
> On occasion it is necessary to aggregate
>   data from a number of rows into a
>   single row, giving a list of data
>   associated with a specific value.

I'm not an Oracle expert; but there are multiple solutions, depending on your DB enviroment.