# how to concatenate query results in the same column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have select query like this; `select id, email from operators where op_code  = 1`

Query result in below;

```
ID     EMAIL
--     -----
1      abc@abc.com
2      xyz@xyz.com
3      def@def.com
```

But I want emails like this format, `abc@abc.com,xyz@xyz.com,def@def.com`

How can I achieve this in Oracle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614373/how-to-use-coalesce-in-oracle-to-combine-data-from-two-rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try below query, which works in ORACLE 11G:

```
select 
  listagg(email, ',') 
    within group (order by id) as list 
from operators
where op_code=1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/58264/1)

OR

```
SELECT 
  (RTRIM(XMLAGG(xmlelement(X, EMAIL||',')order by id).extract('//text()'),',')) list
FROM operators
WHERE op_code=1
```

Comment: Gives this error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: Which is your database version?

Comment: `Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi`

Comment: Please check the second answer(which works in 11G), don't know about 10G.